# CSS Horizontal Menu: display: inline; won't work

Tags: css, menu, inline

I'm on Chrome/Firefox. I've read several tutorials and questions here too on this topic.

I have a UL containing LI. I set the LIs to "display: inline;", but they won't. They're still vertical.

What am I doing wrong?

Thx.

Here's my css:

```
  .menu{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    outline: 1px solid grey;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    font-size:100%;
}

.menu ul{
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

.menu li ul{
    display: none;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    outline: 1px solid gray;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 200;
    left: 20px;
    top: 30%;
}

.menu li:hover ul{
    display: block;
}

.menu li:hover{
    background-color: #005ea2;
}

.menu li{
    display: inline;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted grey;
}

.menu ul li:last-child{
    border: none;
}


.menu a{
    display: block; 
    color: #333333;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.menu a:hover{
    color: white;
    background-color: #005ea2;
}

.menu .menu_header{

    color: #333333;
}

.menu .menu_header a:hover{
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you set .menu ul to float:left? Try to remove it. And also give us the html code.

Comment: Try `display:inline-block;` instead of `display:inline;` (`float:left;` would also work, but has other side-effects)

Comment: @Spudley - inline-block isn't well supported x-browser.

Comment: @annakata - it's much better supported than a lot of people think. IE6 does have big issues with it, but who codes for IE6 these days? IE7 has bugs, but they're easy to work around. All other current browsers and versions are fine.

Answer (score 3):

The `<li>` elements need to have `float:left`

Comment: Maybe. It depends of html. Also that is better way. I do not know why he puts them to be *inline*

Answer (score 0):

first of all you might consider adding the relevant HTML to your answer, to help answerers understand your situation better.

I can spot several strange things that might be related to your problem.

First, the `li ul` selector are not very useful: it's more likely that you meant the opposite, `ul li`.

Second, I see that on hover you have something changing to `display: block`. This is a very 
strange behavior to have on hover, are you sure?

Third, I see that you have `a { display: block }`. This does not play nicely if its container is `display: inline` so you might want to switch to `display: inline-block` for the container (which is what I would suggest for an horizontal menu anyway)

Comment: I think *li ul* is for submenus that is why it is *display:none*. Anyway it would be nice to have html code.

Comment: Thanks! The a{display: block;} was the problem. Ivan is right, the li ul is for submenus.

Comment: inline elements are not allowed to contain block level elements... float was (and generally is) problably the better solution.